# Is there any way to delete useless functions in JS libraries?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm building a project in javascript, using paper.js in some features.
Most of my project is built in vanilla Javascript, just some minimum but important features are built with paper.js

The problem is that the library (.min library) is 200kb.
The normal library is 300kb, I was wondering if there is an automatic way to see which functions are being used in the main paper.js library, in order to delete the useless functions.
If  there is no program or automatic way to do this, maybe some advice of how to do it manually, or which tools you recommend for me and my team in order to delete useless functions, then minify the file and run it smaller.

Thank you all guys, I did not added any specific code because I want this anwser to be global.

Greetings

Comment: What you are describing is commonly called "tree shaking", but unless the library you are using provides a way to do it, there's not much you can do yourself.

Comment: It is generally difficult or impossible to know which functions are actually unused given that you can get functions based on their name as a string, if you now build that string dynamically nobody knows which functions may be needed during runtime.

Comment: Going through a source base as large as paper.js looking for unused code manually would be very difficult and error-prone.

Comment: Also, 200KB doesn't sound that bad. You can load it from cdnjs.com and you don't even have to host it.

Comment: Did you try using the paper-core version which is lighter ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try with paper-core first, I think it has to be done manually, I'll let the question open if I find another way

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually but it's not an easy (and certainly not quick) process. You'll have to find which functions you're using and then find whatever classes or functions those functions reference. You would probably have an easier time creating a new script then copy/pasting what you're using (and any referenced content) then running it with your script, log errors, and repeat.

When you're done there's many minify libraries and services online you can use to minify the new script.

Answer (score 0):

I used the paper-core version and then minified.
I saved 140kb by doing this.
There's still no way to see useless functions in this library